# Peak memory usage of code block?

Tags: php, memory, benchmarking

Is it possible to get the peak memory usage of a particular block of code in PHP?  The [`memory_get_peak_usage()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php) function seems to get the peak over the entire process execution up to the point of the function call, but this is not what I'm trying to obtain, since other code blocks could have skewed the value.  I'm trying to isolate code blocks themselves, rather than the process as a whole.

Example:

```
// Block 1
for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; ++$i) {
    // some code
}

// Block 2
for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; ++$i) {
    // some different code
}

// Determine which of the two blocks used the most memory during their execution here
```

Unfortunately, xdebug is not an option for me at this time.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know a specific function that does this, but if you are just trying to isolate a block of code does something as simple as:

```
$before = memory_get_peak_usage();
for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; ++$i) {
    // some code
}
$after = memory_get_peak_usage();
$used_memory = $after - $before;
```

Comment: I explained in my question why this does not work.

Comment: Just using it once would give you the peak over the whole code up to that point.
However having a variable before and after and subtracting will give you the peak memory usage of that function.

Comment: This will not work the way you think it will for the reasons I outlined in my question.  Because `memory_get_peak_usage()` maintains a running *maximum*, if the code block you've wrapped uses *less* than that maximum, the subsequent call will still show that maximum, and your `$used_memory` will be 0.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT: XHProf does it, check [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16682529/89771).**

---

Don't use `memory_get_peak_usage()`:

```
$alpha = memory_get_usage();

for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; ++$i) {
    // some code
}

$used_memory = memory_get_usage() - $alpha;
```

Bare in mind that this will only return the *final* amount of memory your `// some code` needed. Intermediate memory consumption (such as setting / destroying stuff or calling functions) won't count.

You can hack your way using `register_tick_function()` but it still won't work for function calls.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I specified in the title and question that I'm after the *peak* memory usage of a code block.

Comment: @drrcknlsn: I'm after the same thing (http://stackoverflow.com/q/16511611/89771) but I don't think it's any good. Anyway, like I said in my answer, if you don't care about external function calls in your blocks, you can still get the peak memory usage using the `register_tick_function()`.

Comment: @drrcknlsn: Updated it with a link.