# It is possible to know at what point the script reaches the peak memory?

Tags: php, memory, memory-management

It is possible to know at what point the script reaches the peak memory?

I have a PHP script that at the end shows this result:

> Usage: 380.515625Kb
>
> Peak: 393.5859375Kb
>
> Real: 512Kb

Script example:

```
<?php

...

echo PHP_EOL,
    'Usage: ', memory_get_usage() / 1024, 'Kb', PHP_EOL,
    'Peak: ',  memory_get_peak_usage() / 1024, 'Kb',  PHP_EOL,
    'Real: ',  memory_get_usage(true)  / 1024, 'Kb';
?>
```

The *Peak* is *~13kb* greater than the *Usage*. It is possible to know which part of the code reached the peak of memory usage?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16682529/2518525) seems to do something like what you're asking